# Interesting Property Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Anyone have any ideas why this doesn't work (C# or VB.NET or other .NET language doesn't matter). This is a very simplified example of my problem (sorry for VB.NET):

```
    Private itsCustomTextFormatter As String
    Public Property CustomTextFormatter As String
        Get
            If itsCustomTextFormatter Is Nothing Then CustomTextFormatter = Nothing  'thinking this should go into the setter - strangely it does not'
            Return itsCustomTextFormatter
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value Is Nothing Then
                value = "Something"
            End If
            itsCustomTextFormatter = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

If you do:

```
Dim myObj as new MyClass
Console.WriteLine(myObj.CustomTextFormatter)
```

You will be surprised at the result. It will print "Nothing". Anyone have any idea why it doesn't print "Something"

Here's a Unit Test per suggestion:

```
Imports NUnit.Framework

<TestFixture()> _
Public Class Test
   Private itsCustomTextFormatter As String
    Public Property CustomTextFormatter As String
        Get
            If itsCustomTextFormatter Is Nothing Then CustomTextFormatter = Nothing 'thinking this should go into the setter - strangely it does not' 
            Return itsCustomTextFormatter
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value Is Nothing Then
                value = "Something"
            End If
            itsCustomTextFormatter = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Test()>
    Public Sub Test2()
        Assert.AreEqual("Something", CustomTextFormatter)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This returns:

```
Test2 : Failed  
  Expected: "Something"
  But was:  null

at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(Object expected, Object actual)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `value = "Something"` compiles. Hmm looks like `value` isn't a keyword in VB.net, but just a normal parameter, which explains that it compiles.

Comment: It's a string, you don't have to "New" it when setting it

Comment: @CodeInChaos in C# you can do `value = null;` in a setter

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you compile this simplified program and check that it exhibits the problem?

Comment: The code is a perfect example of NOT HOW DO IT NEVER.  Put the breakpoint at `Return itsCustomTextFormatter` and tell us the complete story :)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Wow, I'm really surprised. I somehow assumed it's constant.

Comment: How did you notice this? No sane person would ever create something like this.

Comment: @Daniel: it returns "Nothing"

Comment: @CodeInChaos - yes I know it perhaps *is* a little odd.  Also, re 'sanity' comment - easily the best comment I've seen all day.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: `value` is a keyword that refers to a *variable*. And of course you can reassign the value of a variable.

Comment: @EricLippert It's quite reasonable once one thinks about `value` as an alias for a normal parameter. But for some reason my brain linked keyword with magic constant instead of variable in this context. I was similarly surprised when I realized that you can assign to `this` in a value type.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Indeed, that surprises a lot of people. The thing to realize about value types is that `void M() { this.x = 123; }` in a value type S is just a nice way of writing `static void M(ref S _this) { _this.x = 123; }`. The `this` has to be *the same variable as the receiver of the call*, otherwise mutable value types are impossible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your comment:

```
'thinking this should go into the setter - strangely it does not'
```

calls out what your error is. In Visual Basic there are two ways to return something from a function:

```
Function GetSomeValue() As String
    Return "Hello"
End Function
```

or

```
Function GetSomeValue() As String
    GetSomeValue = "Hello"
End Function
```

Mixing these two styles is perfectly legal, but confusing and a bad practice:

```
Function GetSomeValue() As String
    GetSomeValue = "Hello" ' I should return Hello... '
    Return "GoodBye"       ' ...or perhaps not. '
End Function
```

As you can see, you are mixing the two styles in the getter. **Setting that variable does not call the setter; it informs the runtime that when the getter returns, this is the value that it should return.** You then override that value with your `Return` statement.

If it hurts when you do that then *don't do that*.

Comment: I am trying to call the "setter" from the "getter". I do this in C# all the time. Is there some problem with that in VB.NET?

Comment: @Denis Yes, there is. Setting [function/property name] = [some value] is essentially assigning just assigning an implicit return value, which gets returned at the end of the method if no other `Return` command is present before the end.

Comment: @Denis 1) Why would you do that? 2) It seems like VB like pascal interprets an assignment to the function name as setting the return value. *(Amazing how a bit of time with C# made me forget how pascal behaved.)* 3) I guess `me.Property = bla` will call the setter.

Comment: wait a second, I think I am starting to see it... So you are saying when I do CustomTextFormatter = Nothing then I am telling it to essentially "Return Nothing". Then what is the return statement doing?

Comment: @GuthMD: so how would I call the "setter" from the "getter" in VB.NET?

Comment: @Denis Setting `CustomTextFormatter = Nothing` is telling `CustomTextFormatter` to default return `Nothing` *if there is no other return statement.* But, you don't get that far, as you instead reach `Return itsCustomTextFormatter`, where the value of `itsCustomTextFormatter` is still nothing, because the Set has not been called.

Comment: @Denis It's poor design to call the the setter from the getter. That said, you may be able to do so by explicitly stating `Me.CustomerTextFormatter = Nothing`.

Comment: @GuthMD: You're absolutely right! Damn VB.NET - you got me again!!!! That's it - this is going to be some poor shmuck's interview question!

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It is indeed an odd practice to call the setter from the getter, but it does occasionally happen. Particularly if the value in question is lazily computed; the getter might check to see if the value is already computed and if so, return it. If not, then it computes it, calls the setter to cache the value for next time, and returns it.

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me in a unit test; albeit in C# (see below).

*(after some playing)*

Ah got it! It's because you're calling `CustomTextFormatter = Nothing` which, in the scope of the Getter is actually just setting the return value of the enclosing accessor method - it's not actually firing the setter (if you put a breakpoint in your setter you will see and debug it you'll see it steps right over it).

Basically you *really* shouldn't be doing this kind of pattern anyway; it's not the way to return a default property value.  This would be better (or to use whatever the equivalent to the C# `??` operator is):

```
Public Property CustomTextFormatter As String
    Get
        If itsCustomTextFormatter Is Nothing Then
            Return "Something"
        End If
        Return itsCustomTextFormatter

    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        itsCustomTextFormatter = value
    End Set
End Property
```

*Original C# Test*

```
    private string _foo;
    private string foo
    {
        get
        {
            if (_foo == null)
                foo = null;
            return _foo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                value = "Something";
            _foo = value;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Something", foo);
    }
```

Comment: @Denis - okay so the first thing we note is it's not .Net - it's either specific to VB or (more likely) specific to *your* VB code.  We just have to find out why.

Comment: FROM COMPILER: 'Set' parameter cannot be declared 'ByRef'

Comment: @Denis - yes (sorry VB not my first language by a long way) - I just figured it out - around the same time Eric updated his answer too; you now have two identical explanations (although Eric's will, by default be better :D)

Comment: I am seeing it. It's a syntax problem. Damn VB.NET you got me again!!!! @Eric is right: "foo = Nothing" is the equivalent of "return Nothing" in VB.NET when used in a "getter" or a function. In C# "foo = Nothing" means call the "setter".

Comment: That's it - this is going to be some poor shmuck's interview question!

Comment: Well, actually, it's not the same as `Return blah` because it doesn't actually return either!

Comment: you're right - it will eventually return it if no other return is being used. Point being, it will not call the "setter" like it does in C#.

Comment: @Denis C# is different from VB, because, erm, C# is a different language from VB. if you want to know why VB has `Return` and also the `<functionname> = <value>` technique: it is for backward compatibility with older versions of VB, which didn't have the `Return` statement for returning values from functions. You should probably prefer the `Return` statement in new code.

Comment: Funny part is "Me.CustomTextFormatter = Nothing" in the "getter" does the right thing and calls the setter and "CustomTextFormatter = Nothing" in the "getter" does something completely different. Go VB.NET language designers! Whoever thought of this should be fired right away!!

Comment: I am a C# developer first and VB.NET developer second so I don't see these things right away - need someone to point these out so VB.NET doesn't drive me crazy.

Comment: @Denis yes Me.CustomTextFormatter will work because it explicitly references the property at *class* scope. Whereas CustomTextFormatter on its own uses the getter's implicit scope, where the name has a specific meaning as being the return value of the function itself. Gnarly, yes, but its part of the language, so hey-ho :D

Comment: @Denis, it makes sense if you know VB 6 and earlier.  These languages did not have a `Return` keyword.  Instead, functions have an implicit variable *using the function name* to hold the return value.  In other words, to return `7` from `Function SomeFunction() As Integer` you would have to have a statement like `SomeFunction = 7`.  The same, confusingly, is true for property getters, so to avoid that you have to use `Me.PropertyName = valueWithWhichToCallSetter`.  VB.NET kept the syntax while also adding a `Return` keyword.

Answer (score -3):

Because you never actually initialized the variable.  You would have to "Set" the property to nothing to actually get "Something".  To fix it you should probably set the default value when declaring the internal variable

```
Private itsCustomTextFormatter As String = "Something"
```

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning.

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant